# Which code is better if I need to use only one static property from PHP class?

Tags: php, yii2

If I need to use only ::class property in my code, should I import a whole class like this?

```
use my\namespace\MyClass;
MyClass::class;
```

Or should I do this?

```
my\namespace\MyClass::class;
```

Which is a faster/better solution? Or there is no difference?
I'm using the Yii2 framework if it matters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference, it is only matter of code style. Both variants generates the same opcodes, so they work the same and there is no performance difference between them. You can use version which suits you better, but importing classes using `use` statement have some advantages:

1. It is more [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself): if you need to use the same class twice, you don't need to repeat FQN twice. It also ensures consistency - there is no risk that in one place you use `my\namespace\MyClass` and in other `some\vendor\namespace\MyClass`.
2. It generates less fuss on refactoring - changing class namespace will only affect import section without touching actual code that uses this class (no meaningless changes in `git blame`).
3. "import everything" is easier to follow and configure CS fixers to ensure this as CS rule.
4. As a result you always have a nice list of classes used in specific file, which may help you find some bugs ("uh, this should be `my\namespace\MyClass` instead of `some\vendor\namespace\MyClass`") and architectural issues ("hmm, there is 60 classes imported in this file, maybe it has too much responsibilities...").

Answer (score 0):

## Namespace :

Both are valid and working properly but in terms of simplicity you can declare it in one line

```
my\namespace\MyClass::class;
```